# Functions on projective double lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I would like to compute the global section of structure sheaf of the 'projective double lines' in projective plane defined by $$X^2=0$$We work over an algebraically closed field $k$, so a first guess is that it should be a two dimensional vector space over $k$ generated by $1$ and $X$.

However, I think the following argument found in Vakil's notes still makes sense, so $h^0$ should be $1$. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Yes, $h^0 = 1$ and $h^1 = 0$. Moreover, $d = 2$.

Comment: @Sasha So am I wrong in taking $X$ as a (non zero) global section? I thought as it squares to $0$, it should be graded $0$ in the graded ring $k[X,Y,Z]/X^2$ so I can always take it as a global section of the structure sheaf.

Comment: @Sasha And once I thought this is a good example that you can't drop the reducedness assumption in the theorem 'connected projective variety has only constant function'.

Comment: $X$ is not a function on the projective plane, it is a section of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$. Its restriction to the double line also gives a section of a line bundle, not a function. If you want a nonreduced example with more global functions, take, e.g., a double point $\{X^2 = Y = 0\}$, or a line with a double point $\{X^2 = XY = 0\}$.

Comment: @Sasha I realize you are right for there is no reason that $X$ should be a global section of the structure sheaf. I made a silly mistake to take $X$ as a weight $0$ homogeneous element in the quotient ring.

Comment: There are 'projective double lines' with nontrivial global functions, though, given in the book Geometry of Schemes. It necesarrily lives in at least $P^3$. I take that fact as 'the double line itself parametrizes some nonreducedness, and when this nonreducedness is twisted suitably, we should get some global section.'

Comment: Indeed, the simplest example is a double line on a smooth quadric surface (it has $h^0 = 2$) or on a smooth cubic surface (it has $h^0 = 3$).